# Do async scripts execute while the HTML parsing continues?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question to the HTML5 async-attribute for script-elements.

MDN says:

> Set this Boolean attribute to indicate that the browser should, if possible, **execute the script asynchronously**

W3Schools says:

> The script is executed asynchronously with the rest of the page (**the script will be executed while the page continues the parsing**)

In contrast to this all the following articles (and their images) say that the HTML parser will pause while executing the async script:

- http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html
- http://peter.sh/experiments/asynchronous-and-deferred-javascript-execution-explained/
- https://bitsofco.de/async-vs-defer/
- https://medium.com/@nikjohn/speed-up-google-maps-and-everything-else-with-async-defer-7b9814efb2b
- https://adamlaki.com/az-async-es-defer-tulajdonsag/
- https://www.keycdn.com/support/defer-parsing-of-javascript/
- http://jecas.cz/async-defer

Who is right? What is true?

Comment: I would never bet on w3schools being the authority.

Comment: Thats why I also quoted MDN!

Comment: It depends since, browsers evolve things change, some browser change faster other don't. have you tried I for your use case? (one of your articles is from 2014, I would forget that one) To quot barney stinson "New is always better". ;-)

Comment: For DOM parsing to continue while JavaScript code runs would mean that sequential statements in JavaScript might detect different DOM state, so I doubt that will ever happen. The illustrations in the second link posted in the OP are accurate.

Comment: According to the whatwg html5 spec at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-async , the diagram shows fetch-in-parallel but parser execution halted, as per your other articles.

Comment: @Pointy exactly, I also thought about this. If a script executes asynchronously the script could bring different DOM results in different lines.

Comment: Here it says, that "the script will be executed asynchronously, as soon as it is available": https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-script-element.html#attr-script-async

Comment: @Teemoh if you keep reading that amazingly complicated description of script execution, I think it's clear that the parser has to stop building the DOM while the script runs.

Comment: Ok but why MDN and W3Schools and even the specs are wrong then?

Comment: I would call the MDN article vague and incomplete, not really wrong. The w3schools article is probably just wrong, but that's hardly surprising. And note that MDN Is a wiki so if you want you can fix it yourself :)

Comment: @Teemoh "asynchronously" has nothing to do with "parallel".